# Temporarily disable parenting

Tags: parent

I have many objects which are parented to an empty object 'A'. Later, I want to change the parent position. I want to move the parent 'A' without moving the children. I need to temporarily disable parenting then move the parent and then enable parenting. This way i can 'reset' the parent to new position.

How can i do it ?

Comment: Hello :). You can simply check *Transform only > Parent* in the sidebar

Comment: Just OMG. it solved my problem.